# Why is my Model null when I wrap the HTML in my View in a "@using (Html.BeginForm(...))" block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Bear with me as it might be quite difficult to explain the issue I am seeing, it is frying my brain because it makes no sense (or I am missing a key component to the logic).

I have a view model object `A` that I am passing from the controller to a strongly typed view `B` which is expecting a model of `A`'s type. When I wrap the HTML in view `B` in a `@using (Html.BeginForm(...))` block (I tried with both `FormMethod.Post` and `FormMethod.Get` just to test), the runtime environment throws an exception when it runs into the following code:

`@for (int i = 0; i < Model.DataTable.Columns.Count; i++)`

Because the `Model` in the code above is null. I stepped through the action that returns view model `A` to view `B` to make sure that I wasn't passing in a null model, and I can guarantee that I am not. In fact, there are some lines where I use LINQ to generate HTML (e.g., yFor(x => x.Report.Name)`) BEFORE the aforementioned`for` loop, and those lines are being processed just fine. When I remove the `` encapsulation block, it works fine.

The kicker is that virtually identical code works in other views with other view models. I am using the same style of `for` loop in another view `C` that expects a view model `D`, and it is all encapsulated in a `` block like I am trying to do with `A` and `B`.

**EDIT:** Here is essentially what it looks like. I hope it's enough. I'm afraid I can't give much more.

```
/* here is a very basic controller action */
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult View()
{
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.Name = "view model test";
    vm.Table = new DataTable();
    return View(vm);
}

/* here is the view */
@model MyMVCProject.Models.ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("View", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h2>Test for: </h2>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)

    <p>Rows</p>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <p>@Model.Table.Rows[i].Name</p>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
}
```

Comment: Strip your controller method and view down to the smallest working (non-working) example and post that code. It's hard to tell from this description what the problem is.

Comment: It's more explicit to describe your code with **actual** code then explaining what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

Ah... this is so embarrassing. I'm pretty sure the compiler was confused between my `View` action and the `View` type which I am returning in the action. I renamed the action and everything is working as expected.